# jQuery Problems with removing event handler with .off()

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have tried to remove an event handler with `.off()`, but it does not work.

I want to remove all event handlers from one certain input:

```
<input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" size="50" />
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
$('#form').on('keyup change', ':input', function() {
    registerChange();
});
$('#form input[name=file_upload]').off();
$('#file_upload').off();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `not` selector for the file upload button

```js
$('#form').on('keyup change', 'input:not([name=file_upload])',  function() {
  registerChange($(this).val());
});

function registerChange(value) {
  // notice that typing into the upload textbox does not log anything to the console
  console.log(value);
}

$('#form').on('click', 'input[name=file_upload]', function () {
  alert('In Click Event Handler, Now Removing Myself');
  // here is how you can remove an event handler
  $('#form').off('click', 'input[name=file_upload]');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <!-- just changeing this to a textbox for demo -->
  <input type="text" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" size="50" value="Choose file" />
</form>
```

Open the console window (<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+J</kbd> in chrome) and type into all of the text boxes. Notice how only the first 2 text boxes write to the console. Also note that the last text box defines an on click handler then removes it, this is why the alert only shows up once.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding event to form element. So in order to remove it you again need to use form tag:

```
// bind delegated events to form element
$('#form').on('keyup change', ':input', function () {
    registerChange();
});

// remove events later
$('#form').off();
```

You are probably confused with [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/): this usage of `on` method attaches events to the form element, where they are captured after bubbling from children `:input`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The problem is, that I want to attach the event to all other inputs of the form (around 200) and just one element does not require the event. I know that I can exclude it before, but it seems not to be the most effizient way.

Comment: @Phantom Then you can specifically stop propagation for these events on this element or filter it out inside `#form` handler using `event.target` or unbind event on FORM level and rebind it excluding specific element using as selector parameter of `on()` method `:input:not(#file_upload)`

Comment: @Wolff Thank you very much. Assuming the form has 200 inputs. Would this be the most effizient way: `$('#' + case_formname).on('keyup change', ':input:not(input[type=file])', function()
 {
  registerChange();
 });`

Comment: @Phantom, just try the demo I made in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#file_upload').off('keyup change', ':input', function()
{
    registerChange();
});
```